# Json not Deserializing List<T> when being called from LabView program

Tags: c#, dll, json.net, labview

So to make a long story short, I have a dll where it's main job is to get data sent to it from a LabView program and then handle some back-end work with said data.

Once the data has been sent to the dll (by calling method of .NET object which has multiple params - see below) and properly parsed into .NET object, if anything goes "bad" (connection to db, any other failure to persist data) I take the data and serialize it to a local folder on the machine in the form of json files.  I am using `Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8` for the json aspect of this project.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public void saveData(string[] someNames, string[] someValues)
    {
        // here I parse the data passed in, and create the .NET object I work with try
        {
            // here I write data to the database, do whatever else I need to do
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // if ANYTHING goes wrong with the persist of data, write json to local file
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I serialize the data:

```
private void writeParentToJson(ParentClass parent)
{
    using (var printer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
    {
        var izer = new JsonSerializer();

        izer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
        izer.Serialize(printer, parent);
    }
}

[JsonObject]
public class ParentClass
{
    [JsonProperty("childThings")]
    public List<ChildClass> listOfChildClass { get; set; }

    public ParentClass()
    {

    }

    public ParentClass(List<ChildClass> listOfChildClass)
    {
        this.listOfChildClass = listOfChildClass;
    }
}

[JsonObject]
public class ChildClass
{
    [JsonProperty("childName")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("childValue")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    public ChildClass()
    {

    }

    public ChildClass(string name, string value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

When this happens, everything writes fine to the json file.  When I read the data again, this is how I do it:

```
public ParentClass loadParentFromJson()
{
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(filePath)))
    {
        var izer = new JsonSerializer();
        izer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;

        return izer.Deserialize<ParentClass>(reader);
    }
}
```

When I create a .NET project and use this dll... everything works flawlessly.  The problem is that the person using LabView is not so lucky.  Everything works fine when the dll *writes* the data to the file, but *reading* it back is where we are having the issue.

More specifically, this happens: *Inner Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyDll.ChildClass, MyDll]]' in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'*

I don't know anything about LabView, and the person using LabView doesn't know anything about .NET.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The LabView program only calls the method, the dll does all the reading/writing of json.. which is why I don't know how it works for me, but not when called from the LabView program.

All computers have .NET 4.0 framework installed..  I have seen others with this exception, but it only fails when being called from LabView program.. and I have no idea why.

Comment: Looks like LabView is not using the right runtime. See http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/32B0BA28A72AA87D8625782600737DE9

Comment: Well I did not think of that, but the LabView guy just checked, and he is running 2013 which defaults to .NET 4.0 and there is no config file in the project that would change the default.  I am going to try and change the load method to use `dynamic` and see if that parses properly.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475345/assembly-gettype-fails-to-load-list1mymodel-type-from-resharper-plugin-on

Answer (score 0):

NI have a couple of application notes that I use each time I use a new Installation on LabVIEW:

http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvhowto/configuring_clr_version/

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4742EB60B64BE22186257BCE0053B8FD

These describe setting the LabVIEW.exe.config file to allow the usage of 3rd part .Net assemblies (and for different .Net versions), ultimately I end up with a LabVIEW.exe.config as follows:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
        </startup>
        <runtime>
            <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
        </runtime>
    </configuration>
```